# How to speedup java maven build on Google Cloud Build (100s of dependencies)

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-build

I am using [Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) to build a java project which has 100s of dependencies. By default the local maven repository cache will be empty and it **downloads all dependencies each time there is a build**.

The google documentation only suggests "Caching directories with Google Cloud Storage" https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds but it takes a long time to sync 7000 files (which means the build is slower)

just one dependency is 5 files

```
repository/org/mockito
repository/org/mockito/mockito-core
repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0
repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/mockito-core-2.15.0.jar
repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/mockito-core-2.15.0.jar.sha1
repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/mockito-core-2.15.0.pom
repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/mockito-core-2.15.0.pom.sha1
repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/_remote.repositories
```

An example cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['rsync', '-r', 'gs://my-mavencache-bucket/repository', '.']

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mvn'
  args: ['package']
...
```

I would like to mount gs://my-mavencache-bucket at as a volume - but I dont see an option to do that

Comment: do you have an example of the project? Furthermore are you using most recent version of Maven and all Plugins ? etc.

Comment: Could you update your question with a metric on the slowness?  Can you provide a measurement of how long the build is taking?  If you compiled locally on a PC with nothing already downloaded into caches, how long does it take there?

Comment: I have been using maven for many years, the issue is not the version of maven or some configuration, it to do with the way google cloud build works - A build is a set of steps where each step is the equivalent of a docker run command and /workspace is a common directory shared by these steps. Given that Google Cloud Build is a recommended standard for building and I am using a java monolith application(pretty mainstream use case), I would have hoped to find an example by now but no luck yet

Comment: Seems crazy googles cloudbuild is missing this most basic need.  Makes build take 15 minutes rather than 2 minutes in our case.  Jenkins, Bitbucket etc take care of caching the maven repository.

Answer (score 2):

After much experimentation, this solution seems to work quite well. [google-storage-wagon](https://egkatzioura.com/2018/04/09/host-your-maven-artifacts-using-google-cloud-storage/).  This maven plugin provides a mechanism to read and publish maven artifacts from a google 
 data bucket

Maven pom.xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repo-bucket-release</id>
            <url>gs://bucket-ave-build-artifact/external</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <!-- TODO figure out why checksums do not match when artifact pulled from GCP -->
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>my-repo-bucket-snapshot</id>
            <url>gs://my-build-artifact-bucket/snapshot</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repo-bucket-release</id>
            <url>gs://my-build-artifact-bucket/release</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
...
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>com.gkatzioura.maven.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-storage-wagon</artifactId>
                <!-- version 1.8 seems to produce exception, ticket logged -->
                <version>1.7</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

    </build>
```

and cloudbuild.yaml is simply

```
steps:
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  # -X here simply for verbose maven debugging
  args: ['deploy', '-X']
```

this will:

1. maven publish artifacts to a data bucket
   gs://my-build-artifact-bucket/release
2. download external dependencies
   from gs://my-build-artifact-bucket/external (if they exist in this directory)

Comment: Another mechanisms is to build a custom docker image which contains most of the the maven artifacts inside the .m2 cache. This results in a slightly slower launch time of the custom build step since as the larger image needs to be pulled from the https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/.

Comment: But then you need to push each dependency artifact separately?

Answer (score 0):

I found the package [google-storage-wagon](https://egkatzioura.com/2018/04/09/host-your-maven-artifacts-using-google-cloud-storage/) very nice, but lacking in terms of authentication and timing of the synchronization.

I implemented it myself like follows. For more information about service accounts refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56610260/1236401

So assuming you have your service account `key.json` file handy and you have the name of your `SERVICE_ACCOUNT` as well as a storage bucket `BUCKET_PATH`, this is the basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-12

ENV MAVEN_PATH="/root/.m2" \
    BUCKET_PATH="gs://mugen-cache/maven"
COPY key.json /key.json

# install gcloud sdk
RUN mkdir -p $MAVEN_PATH && \
    yum install -y curl which && \
    curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin" \
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT="mugen-build@mugen.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
# authenticate service account and install crcmod - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CRC32CandInstallingcrcmod
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT --key-file=/key.json && \
    yum install -y gcc python-devel python-setuptools redhat-rpm-config
RUN curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py" && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    pip uninstall crcmod && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -U crcmod

RUN echo "Syncing m2 in..." && \
    gsutil -q -m rsync -r $BUCKET_PATH $MAVEN_PATH && \
    echo "Downloaded $(find $MAVEN_BUCKET -type f -name "*.pom" | wc -l) packages"

# ... build and stuff

RUN echo "Syncing m2 out..." && \
   gsutil -q -m rsync -r $MAVEN_PATH $BUCKET_PATH
```

Some of the instructions here are specific to the base image (which is the REHL-based Oracle Linux Server), but you should be able to extract the important details in order to make it work in your case.