# Give access to a google storage bucket to Google Build while building a Docker image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I am new to google cloud services and I am trying to set up an automatic build of my production requiring to download a heavy file.

I would like to download a file from a dedicated Google Storage bucket inside the Docker build process. To do so, I have added the following line to my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN curl https://storage.cloud.google.com/[bucketname]/[filename] -o [filename]
```

Since files from this bucket shouldn't be publicly accessible, I disabled object level permission and added to the member `[ProjectID]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` the right `Storage Object Viewer`.

But when the docker file script run, the file downloaded is empty

```
Step 7/9 : RUN curl https://storage.cloud.google.com/[bucketname]/[filename] -o [filename]
 ---> Running in 5d1a5a1bbe87
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Removing intermediate container 5d1a5a1bbe87
 ---> 42938a9cc8d1
Step 8/9 : RUN ls -l [filename]
 ---> Running in 34ac112051a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 15 00:37 [filename]
```

This link works perfectly well if I login in google.console and access it through my navigator.

I tried changing the permission settings, and ended up adding `cloud build account`, `storage legacy bucket reader`, `storage legacy object reader`, `storage object viewer` together without much success.

I am obviously doing something wrong. But its not clear to me if:

- This link format is only valid in the console and I should use an other URL to get this file
- The permission configuration is wrong
- I still have to process to some http authorization through curl
- I am overlooking something else.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 7):

After a long research, try and error, I managed to find out a good way to do it. here is the recipe for those whou may need to reproduce a similar setup, and my future me.

- Create a service account in *console.cloud.google.com* / *AIM & Admin* dedicated to this task (You can also use cloud shell https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)
- Generate a key for this service account (you can use the web console or type `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/key.json --iam-account [SA-NAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com` in *Cloud Shell*   (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-gcloud)
- Add this file to your repository. Install *Cloud Shell* to your Docker so that you can log in (right, you are going to install a whole sdk just to log in...) :

```
RUN curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin"
```

- Now, in a shell script run by `RUN ./myscript.sh` from your docker file, you will add:

  - Activate your service account with `gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=~/key.json` (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)
  - You can generate an authentification token associated to this account with `` TOKEN=`gcloud auth print-access-token [ACCOUNT]` `` (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-access-token)
  - Finaly, you can add the curl command :

  ```
  RUN curl -L  -H "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[bucketname]/o/[objectname]?alt=media -o filename
  ```

  I did not used `gcloud cp gs://bucketname/bucketfile ./` because `python2` was not available in my Docker image and python3 isn't supported by google.

*Congratulate* yourself with a *chocolat cake* or a sugary treat. (:

Bonus: If like me your docker build timeout, you have to add a `cloudbuild.yaml` next to your `Dockerfile`. Here is a generic file I use for my builds:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$BUILD_ID', '.' ]
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$BUILD_ID'
timeout: 900s
```

Comment: Hi there! This step by step guide of yours helped me out a lot today! However, I'd like to add following recommendations:

First: You're advising people to store the service account secret key - in the repo. This is very bad practice, especially if the repo is public. Also, you would not want to store the service account name in the docker file. Instead, provide both SA-Name and Key via docker build-arg (key=b64 encoded), and store them in the image during build time. Also, remove gcloud and key at the end, if not needed at runtime.

Comment: Second: In my case, I used the python-3.8 image; not sure if that was unsupported at the time you were writing it. But after enabling the service account, I could just use the gsutil commands normally like `RUN gsutil cp gs://$MODELS_BUCKET/...`. No token needed.